# get data from html page with windows phone c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone, html-agility-pack

I have this page: www.unnu.com/music-artists

need to retrieve this complete list of all the artists and their links.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

            // There are various options, set as needed
            htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;

            // filePath is a path to a file containing the html
            htmlDoc.Load("http://www.unnu.com/music-artists");

            // Use:  htmlDoc.LoadHtml(xmlString);  to load from a string (was htmlDoc.LoadXML(xmlString)

            // ParseErrors is an ArrayList containing any errors from the Load statement
            if (htmlDoc.ParseErrors != null && htmlDoc.ParseErrors.Count() > 0)
            {
                // Handle any parse errors as required

            }
            else
            {

                if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
                {
                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode bodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a");

                    if (bodyNode != null)
                    {
                        listBox1 = ????//this is not working, do not know if the code is correct and just missing here or is this all wrong.
                    }
                }
            }
```

Please, I need this with urgency as it is a job. If you need my skype is gnrmalazagnr can add.

Comment: What's `listBox1`? By the way, I would not add my contact information in question. I recommend removing it.

Comment: is where you want to receive the contents of all of this, if the links. Would be placed inside this box links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to do here, but if just want to download and read the html file. you need 

`WebClient web = new WebClient();
web.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("www.unnu.com/music-artists"));
web.DownloadStringCompleted += web_DownloadStringCompleted;`

`void web_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string HtmlPage = e.Result;
        }`

Comment: the idea is to put the list of artists that have that address in my list box. I do not know how to do this, but I spent researching this code is the closest I could get. Your code is valid but does not know how to assign my list

Comment: this error: Error 1 The type 'System.Xml.XPath.IXPathNavigable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml.XPath, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. C:\Users\Luiz Negrini\Desktop\Windows Phone\AppUnno\AppUnno\MainPage.xaml.cs 307 12 AppUnno

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem thanks:

void web_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
            {

```
            if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result))
            {
                _artistas = new List<Artista>();
                // Aqui você pega todos os links da página
                // P.S.: Se a página mudar, você tem que alterar o pattern aqui.
                string pattern = @"\<a\shref\=[\""|\'](?<url>[^\""|\']+)[\""|\']\stitle\=[\""|\'](?<title>[^\""|\']+)[\""|\']\>(?<author>[^\<]+)\<\/a\>";
                // Busca no HTML todos os links
                MatchCollection ms = Regex.Matches(e.Result, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

                Debug.WriteLine("----- OK {0} links encontrados", ms.Count);

                foreach (Match m in ms)
                {
                    // O pattern acima está dizendo onde fica o Url e onde fica o nome do artista
                    // e esses são resgatados aqui
                    Group url = m.Groups["url"];
                    Group author = m.Groups["author"];

                    if (url != null && author != null)
                    {
                        //Debug.WriteLine("author: {0}\nUrl: {1}", author.Value, url.Value);

                        // Se caso tenha encontrado o link do artista (pois há outros links na página) continua
                        if(url.Value.ToLower().IndexOf("/artist/") > -1)
                        {
                            // Adiciona um objeto Artista à lista
                            Artista artista = new Artista(author.Value, url.Value);
                            _artistas.Add(artista);
                        }
                    }
                }

                listBox1.ItemsSource = _artistas;

            }
        }
```